# how can I sub in values in a dataframe with an if statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv that i'm turning into a dataframe and sometimes the 'money markets' key in column ' security type name' changes to 'CASH' in 'CUSIP'. I'm trying to write an if statement that causes my function to grab from 'CASH' instead of 'money markets' when it finds an empty value. My function returns without an error but is still missing the values. I don't want to provide the whole code or dataframe because it's obnoxiously large and am hoping you can just easily spot what I'm doing wrong here. Hope you can help!

```
account_names = ["Account 1", "Account 2"]
money_market_name = ["Money Market Fund"]
cash_name = "CASH"

smmh = df[df["Account Name"].isin(account_names) & df["Security Type Name"].isin(money_market_name)]
moneymarkets = smmh['Market Value'].sum()
if moneymarkets.size == 0:
    smmh = df[df["Account Name"].isin(account_names) & df["CUSIP"].isin(cash_name)]
```

Comment: Can you add sample input and the desired output.

Comment: Should `cash_name` be a list rather than string? Otherwise `df["CUSIP"].isin(cash_name)` will only return True for `'C, 'A', 'S', 'H'`